How to add new product type in plugin dokan
enter image description here
I want to add a custom product to this section in the shop plugin, put it in the name of the auction and my own fields, and the codes I wrote, but I did not get the result, are as follows.
add_filter('dokan_product_types', 'add_custom_product_type_to_dokan');
function add_custom_product_type_to_dokan($types){
    $types['auction'] = __('مزایده', 'dokan');
    return $types;
}

